# HTML &amp; case sensitive

Tags: html

HTML in general is case insensitive. However I`ve noticed some escape names are case sensitive. For example , `&Aacute;` and `&aacute;`.
Is `&amp;` case sensitive regarding HTML standard?

Comment: Note that the name is case sensitive: in HTML, &Aacute; represents the uppercase letter Á, whereas &aacute; represents the lowercase á.
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reserved entities in HTML are case sensitive.

Browsers will be nice to you and accept whatever you give them, but you should be using the proper casing.

See also:  https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#named-character-references

Comment: I suppose correct one is low case: &amp;. thank you

Comment: @Alex That is correct, `&amp;` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From the below resource:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-entities.php

> Note: HTML entities names are case-sensitive! Please check out the
> HTML character entities reference for a complete list of character
> entities of special characters and symbols

And From https://www.youth4work.com/Talent/html/Forum/117977-is-html-case-sensitive

> Generally, HTML is case-insensitive, but there are a few exceptions.
> Entity names (the things that follow ampersands) are case-senstive,
> but many browsers will accept many of them entirely in uppercase or
> entirely in lowercase; a few must be cased in particular ways. For
> example, Ç is Ç and ç is ç. Other combinations of upper
> and lower case are no good.